# How to run putty with -m command line *and* get log?

Tags: centos6, log-files, putty, nohup

I'd like to launch putty and run my script automatically, it works, but I can't save the logs (I need them to debug)!

The way I call putty:

```
"D:\Some-Path\putty\PUTTY.EXE" -t -load "Server - 111.22.33.444" -l root -m "D:\Cmd\param-1.sh"
```

`param-1.sh` contains two lines:

```
cd /full/path/
sudo bash /full/path/long_process.sh "param 1" "param-2.txt" "param 3" 0
```

It works just fine, but if I change `param-1.sh` to get the script execution logs, ie.

```
sudo bash /full/path/long_process.sh "param 1" "param-2.txt" "param 3" 0 > /path/_Logs/param-1.txt &
```

No log is saved, in fact the script isn't even executed!

I tried adding `nohup` before the `sudo bash...`, it didn't work either

Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

With the `&` at the end, you put the process into the background, preventing `sudo` from running properly. Why did you add it if it isn't required in the non-logging version?